# Why err when me export class?

Tags: node.js

I have built models NodeJs. But I don't understand why the error at the moment:

export default Products = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema);
^

ReferenceError: Products is not defined

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    image: String,
    discount: {
      type: Number,
      require: false,
    },
  });


export default Products = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema);
```

Comment: Default exports can't be named as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a named default export. You would have to write it like so:

```js
export default mongoose.model("Products", productSchema);
```